# AJAX request firing 4 times instead of once

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My code should only fire once on receiving a request from the server via AJAX, however it seems to be firing off about 4 times.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to prevent it?
I have tested this on Chrome and IE

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX Test</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divOne">
            Test
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</html>
```

**client.js**

```
var xmlhttpSend;
xmlhttpSend = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttpSend.onreadystatechange=function(){
    //The code in this area should only fire once on receiving a response
    //from the server (but it seems to run 4 times)

    var getText = xmlhttpSend.responseText;
    document.getElementById('divOne').innerHTML = getText;
    alert(getText);

}
xmlhttpSend.open("POST", "server.php?q="+encodeURIComponent("test"), true);
xmlhttpSend.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttpSend.send();
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    echo 'ok';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event onreadystatechange fires everytime the state changes, there are 5 states as you see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

You probably want something like this :

```
if (xmlhttpSend.readyState==4 && xmlhttpSend.status==200){ ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this w3schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) that sounds like the correct behavior, as the `readyState` will change from 0 to 4 in increments of 1 during the request cycle.

Comment: This answer links to w3schools which can not be considered an authoritative source unlike the MDN that is linked to in the other answer.